# Can't get remote: true to work with link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't trigger my js file for some reason. Why is that?

**views/categories/_category.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to category.name, articles_path(categotry_id: category.id), remote: true %>
```

**views/articles/index.js.coffee**

```
alert 'I am here'
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def index
end
```

Comment: Do you receive a response from your server ? (open your console in chrome browser, go to network tab, click on your JS link and see if the request is sent and answered by your server, also check if it contains the JS you want). You might want to try with a simple `console.log('hello')` just in case the alert is not acceptable in a AJAX response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing response format js in index action:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would need to call `render` in your controller, and have a action, and a route... Try generating a scaffold to see what all you're missing.